# Why does my django post.publish return the date with midnight when it's not published at midnight

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out why my post.publish keeps adding midnight next to it. I followed a tutorial and he didn't have that problem. Heres my code

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
       ('draft', 'Draft'),
       ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              height_field='height_field',
                              width_field='width_field')
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    video_path = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

my forms.py

```
   class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
   publish = forms.DateField(
       widget=forms.SelectDateWidget,
       initial=datetime.date.today
   )

   class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = [
           "title",
           "body",
           "author",
           "image",
           "video_path",
           "video",
           "publish",
           "tags",
           "status"
       ]
```

I'm not sure sure what it is.

Comment: Probably the `SelectDateWidget` (as its name suggests) only posts a date which django translates to a datetime object with hour, minute, second, etc. set to their default `0`.

Comment: I set the default to zero still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though I havent figured out what causes my problem I found a way to make it disappear by adding

```
{% post.publish | date %}
```

it annoys me I don't know whats causing it but This is the band aid